# Qt Code Editor on QPlainTextEdit How to tab the code

Tags: c++, qt, text-editor

I am trying to implement a simple dialog to edit some part of code. I use [this](http://pepper.troll.no/s60prereleases/doc/widgets-codeeditor.html) which is based on QPlainTextEdit. However, I cannot insert tab into code text. The main reason could be that I show the Code editor as dialog as seen in the code. When I press Tab button the dialog closes and then reopens.

```
CodeEditor* editor = new CodeEditor(this);
editor->setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog);
editor->setMinimumSize(400, 400);
editor->show();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks guys,

I solved the problem and it is totally about the part I did not mention in the question. This code is part of [qtpropertybrowser](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/solutions/4/qtpropertybrowser/index.html) code base. I am trying to add a property editor which will open code editing widget I pointed out in the question. When I drill down the qt property code base, I found that tab key is neglected because, it is filtered by eventFilter. When I change this part. I solved the problem.

but, I couldn't solve the problem that the editor is closed and reopened. It becomes so quick. And and error message is outputted as follows QWidget::setTabOrder: 'first' and 'second' must be in the same window.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Qt::Window` instead of `Qt::Dialog` and make it application modal by using `QWidget::setWindowModality()`.

Comment: This does not work. When I click tab button, the editor is closed and reopened. It becomes so quick. And and error message is outputted as follows QWidget::setTabOrder: 'first' and 'second' must be in the same window

Answer (score 0):

I would embed the editor in a QDialog with OK and Cancel buttons. Also, make sure that QPlainTextEdit::tabChangesFocus() is false.

Comment: This does not work. When I click tab button, the editor is closed and reopened. It becomes so quick. And and error message is outputted as follows: QWidget::setTabOrder: 'first' and 'second' must be in the same window

Comment: Weird. So setTabChangesFocus( false ) has no effect? Which platform are you on?